# Parse value from format constString1_Value_conString2

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse an HTML string. I need to parse `value` from strings in this format:

```
title="Profil">VALUE</a>
```

The value can have any number of characters and it must end with  `</a>`.

Comment: "Hi, I need parse html string with regExp. I have one problem" - now you have two ;-)

Comment: Do you want to parse HTML with regular expression?

Answer (score 2):

This can be very simple using an HTML parser and some [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), which is probably a better choice than a regex. Here's an example using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(@"http://jsbin.com/onoho3");
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@title='Profil']");
string myValue = node.InnerText;
```

Of course, you can also load the document from a string:

```
HtmlDocument doc =new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

If you do need a regex, a few possibilies are:
 `title="Profil">.*?</a>`, `title="Profil">[^<>]*</a>`, or `title="Profil">\w*</a>`, depending exactly on what you need. Since you don't have any special characters, the regex is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use HTML Agility Pack to processes HTML documents, it can be found from here:

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to use a RegEx and your text always must end with a dot (.) you can use this:

```
Regex valuePattern=new Regex( @"title=""Profil"">(.*\.)</a>");
string value = "";
Match match = valuePattern.Match(text);

if(match.Success)
    value = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

For parsing HTML I would suggest [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) as well though, it makes many common parsing problems much easier.